# How to replace a pattern in ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My array server_ip has the below values:
"[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]"

However, I want the array to be as below:
"172.31.25.207", "172.31.21.29"

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, where you want to know how to retrieve the values from a string representation of an array of strings, when you SHOULD be asking how should `server_ip` be created in the first place to avoid the problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

```
"[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]"
```

looks like a string representation of array.

To convert it back to array, try one of the below options

```
1. JSON.parse("[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]")
2. YAML.load("[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]")
3. eval("[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]")
4. "[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]".scan(/[\d\.]+/)
```

All will work

Comment: Good answer. Perhaps add 4. `"[\"172.31.25.207\", \"172.31.21.29\"]".scan(/[\d\.]+/) `.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks, I added it to the answer

Comment: A better question is WHY is the data being received like this.