# Modifying an array in Ruby with some other text

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to modify an array, which looks like:

```
arr = [ ' \"172.31.25.207\" ', ' \"172.31.21.29\" ' ]
```

However, I want the array to look like:

```
arr = "172.31.25.207", "172.31.21.29"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33573544/4283486

Comment: Since you asked an almost identical question very recently I feel obligated to ask where you are getting these "Arrays"?

Comment: This, like the previous question, looks like an XY problem, where you're asking about Y but need to ask about X. What are you doing to retrieve the values as strings enclosed in double-quotes? You're not showing us enough information to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `arr.map {|e| e.gsub('\"', '').strip }`

Example output:

```
irb> [ ' \"172.31.25.207\" ', ' \"172.31.21.29\" ' ].map  {|e| e.gsub('\"', '').strip }
=> ["172.31.25.207", "172.31.21.29"]
```